# Timeout in AS3 events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, netconnection

I have a NetConnection object:

```
myNetConnection = new NetConnection();
myNetConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusHandler);
myNetConnection.connect("rtmp://address");
```

And in handler do this:

```
private function statusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
            {
                switch (event.info.code)
                {
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success": 
                    {
                        trace("ok");
                        break;
                    }
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
                    {
                        trace("Some problems, NetConnection.Connect.Failed");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

So, if all ok - I have see "ok" in debug console very fast.
But if have any problems - "Some problems, NetConnection.Connect.Failed" I see after long time waiting.
My question - how i can see "Some problems, NetConnection.Connect.Failed" faster(as "ok" fast)?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely can't. The event is triggered as fast as it can be, it's the connection failure that is taking a long time to manifest itself.

It looks to me like the problem is that the connection attempt times out. Flash tries to connect and sets a timer, if the timer fires before the connection is established Flash concludes that the resource is not available. You can't get a failure at once, because the connection does not fail until the timer has fired.

Flash can't tell you immediately that the resource is not available because sometimes a server responds within milliseconds, but sometimes it can take seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that if Flash Player fails to connect to the server with the normal protocol (RTMP, port 1935) it automatically tries to establish a connection using fallback protocols and ports. The normal sequence is:

> netConnection.connect("rtmp://myserver/myapp");
>   // uses the default port 1935
>   netConnection.connect("rtmp://myserver:443/myapp");
>   netConnection.connect("rtmp://myserver:80/myapp");
>   netConnection.connect("rtmpt://myserver:80/myapp");

All this attempts increase the final timeout for the connection.

> This automatic retry sequence occurs
>   only if the initial connection
>   specifies the RTMP protocol and uses
>   the default port--for example,
>   my_nc.connect("rtmp://myserver/myapp").

You can found more information [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000166.html).